# Using local API endpoint for message processor issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm trying to create a retry mechanism which will be recall my API (using POST method) in case of error (for example HTTP 400)

For this reason, I've created an In Memory Message Store. If my REST call is failed, I send the message to the message store that I created.

Then I tried to create an endpoint which is the same API URL (Scheduled Message Forwarding Processor will be used that)  in WSO2 Management Console UI:

[image: WSO2 Endpoint]

, but I've got the following error when I click the Test button:

[image]

Interesting thing is I can access the API with Postman or through my application but, WSO2 itself cannot access the API which is available on it.

I realized that when I click the test button, WSO2 adds `?wsdl` at the end of the endpoint that I try and only available `GET` APIs can be recalled by message processor with this method but my API using `POST` method, and I need to recall it.

I'm using WSO EI 6.4.0

Thanks for any idea!

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For connection to REST API, you should use HTTP Endpoint, not the Address Endpoint
.

**But** you may consider extracting the logic you want from your API into a sequence and using the Message Sampling Processor to push messages to that sequence rather than your own REST API. This could be a more efficient solution.

Comment: Hi @tmoasz, thanks for the quick reply. I also tried using HTTP Endpoint, but I got the same error 'Invalid Address, Unable to estabilish a connection'.I added my API endpoint as URI Template in console. I'll consider and try your other recommendation also.

Comment: @BK. do not worry about the result of this button Test. I think it only works for SOAP - Web Services, For HTTP Endpoint i also have errors, but Endpoints work properly.

Comment: With using Message Sampling Processor way, I can successfully retry the API call :) Just one issue left which is the header parameters and axis2 properties like To are removed I think when the second call executed. Because I'm logging the header parameters and To property value in DB. For the To value, the logged value changed as http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous

Comment: Before Store the message, you set in the properties mediators: 'To' or any interesting values from header. They persist in message context, so after Message Processor you can easy get them back.